# Non www. version of site not displaying

Tags: php, dns

I have a site currently live at ssaib.uk.com but when you try and access the site at www.ssaib.uk.com you get nothing. It is not down to domain propagation and I have no idea why it is doing it. I've read mention it could be a conflict between xcache and eaccelerator however I have turned eaccelerator off without result. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is due to DNS settings. You need a record for the domain WITHOUT www., usually represented in your domain management panel as an @ or blank or *.

Comment: I need a record for the "without" when it's the "with" that is not working? You'll notice if you ping www.ssaib.uk.com it resolves to the correct IP address so it seems to be something on the server not getting the domain to the correct directory... unless I'm totally wrong here?

Comment: Yes, in that case you are correct, it must be due to the configuration of the so-called virtual hosts not recognising .ssaib.uk.com as the same virtual host as www.ssaib.uk.com. Since they ARE technically different addresses, you need to ensure the configuration of the web server assumes them to be the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If the DNS is resolving but the website isn't showing up, it could be that the web server is configured only to respond to certain hostnames - Apache for example has "virtual hosts" with different document roots, for example one could respond to "example.com" and another to "somesite.com" even though they resolve to the same IP.

Have a look in your web server settings.

Comment: Ok, it's an apache server with cgi running cpanel. Diff to my last server but not sure where that file would be?

Comment: It will be somewhere like `/etc/apache2.2/conf.d/httpd.conf`. Think it's time for you to read the Apache manpage with regards to virtual hosts now.